# Filtering Tablix based on date field

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have a report that returns basic rows of data. I need to filter this and only get data for yesterday. I was looking into adding a filter to the tablix, choosing the date field, setting operator value to =, and then using Today(), but cannot seem to manipulate Today() using -1 or anything similar.

Any other expression suggestion would be welcome.

Also, for the same dataset, I need to filter for yesterday based on one date filed as long as another date field is not the same date. example, amended date is yesterday, but created date is not the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways of achieving this. You can do it via the filter using two filters, first `> dateadd("d",-1,Today())` and second `< Today()`. But I would recommend using parameters in your SQL rather than doing it at the report stage. In your SQLs WHERE clause you can add

```
    WHERE ...
And
    [date field] BETWEEN @StartDate and @EndDate
```

Then you can create two Date/Time type parameters in your report @StartDate and @EndDate and use those to manipulate the data as needed. Then you can set the default for those parameters to be whatever you want and when running the report it will give you (or your end user) a calendar to pick whichever date range you/they like. Again if you wanted only "yesterdays" data you could set your default @StartDate to `=dateadd("d",-1,Today())` and your @EndDate default to `=Today()` That way your extraneous data will be excised at the SQL level meaning you don't waste resources importing more data than you require and you don't have to mess about with changing the filters if you want a one off run of the report for a different date range.